# Background image of Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

How can I **include an image as the background** and where and how to put an image in the application, I am using Eclipse and all the development tools.

Here's what I have ***done so far*** in the main_activity.xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#C0C0C0"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:background="#c0c0c0" is the bg color i have set at the moment ill erase that line once i get image bg to work

Comment: change your color to android:background="@drawable/your_background_img"

Comment: You will have to keep the image in res/drawable folder of your project

Answer (score 3):

put your image in res/drawable directory

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/your_imagename"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

just search and you will get it.

just put your image inside `res/drawable` folder and change

```
android:background="#C0C0C0"
```

to

```
android:background="@drawable/your_image_name" (dont give extension of image)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a .jpg or .png image inside the res/drawable folder and change the background attribute to this:

```
android:background="@drawable/image-name"
```

where `image-name` is the actual name of the image.

As you'll see, there are several drawable folders, like drawable-mdpi or drawable-hdpi. They are designed to store images for devices with different screen density. To make sure your application looks good on different devices, provide alternative images for every density. The `@drawable/image-name` attribute doesn't need to be changed then, the Android will pick the right drawable folder for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gaurav, Nevertheless, they are valid formats. Of course it's preferable to use PNG.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `.jpg` and `.png` format images. after that, 
copy your image and paste it in `res` Folder in your application. 
if the name of your image is `image.png`

use this code..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/image"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @PadmaKumar, yes this is right, and if you want to use your image in a ImageView with another Background color then you can use.           android:background="#000" (#000= black color)
android:src="@drawable/image.png"

Comment: oh I asked that can we do "@drawable/image.png"? Ans is no, no need to mention the file extension. thanks for your edit.

Comment: @PadmaKumar::-  ohkies.. I didn't get your question that's why. But yes , if you use extension, it will give you an error.